# jQuery add / remove class

Tags: jquery

I have five divs:

```
<div class="tip tip-1 activeTip"></div>
<div class="tip tip-2"></div>
<div class="tip tip-3"></div>
<div class="tip tip-4"></div>
<div class="tip tip-5"></div>
```

I would like to use the jQuery on click event to add the activeTip class to a div and also remove it from the div it is currently set on. So only one div should have the activeTip class at a time.

Thanks

Comment: Start with binding `click` event handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

following will do the job if you want click event on these divs

```
$(".tip").click(function(){
  $(".activeTip").removeClass("activeTip");
  $(this).addClass("activeTip");
})
```

if you want the click event in some other place, you have to put data tag in that and add class depend on the data value of that element